# Get the processing time of cube in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

Quick question - How do we capture the process runtime of azure analysis cube?  it gets triggered using web activity in Azure data factory.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [sample](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#processazureas) which starts an Azure AS model processing and then loops until the most recent processing batch is complete.

Comment: Thanks @GregGalloway